# Hausdorff Dimension Calculation

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

This is a homework question that I don't know where to start with it. Can somebody help me please? I am trying to work out the Hausdorff dimension of the set $\{0,1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},...\}$.

I have worked this sort of thing out for a couple of fractal examples, but never for a set of numbers and I am pretty confused.

Comment: The definition ("Hausdorff dimension") is usually a reasonable place to start with homework questions.  Presumably the topology considered here is the metric inherited from the real number line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hausdorff dimension is defined in terms of covers. Try drawing out the points in this set - you'll notice that there's an accumulation point at $0$. If you place an interval of length $\delta$ just barely covering $0$, how many of the points in your set did you cover? How many intervals do you need to cover the remaining points? What does that tell you about the Hausdorff dimension, as you take $\delta$ to be arbitrarily small?

Comment: Thank for your response. So it has taken so long for me to get back to you. So at stage $k$, there are $k+1$ points which can be covered by intervals of size $\delta=1/k^{2}$?

Comment: @GerrySmith Right. So the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of your set is bounded by $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left((k + 1) \cdot \frac{1}{k^2}\right)^s$, for each $s$. For which values of $s$ does that go to $0$? To $\infty$?

Comment: Ok thank you. So as I understand it, $\left(\frac{k+1}{k^{2}}\right)^{s}$ diverges to $\infty$ for all $s<0$, is obviously $1$ for $s=0$, and converges for all $s>0$. Is this correct?

Comment: @GerrySmith Correct. Since the critical point is $s = 0$, the Hausdorff dimension of the set is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do we know that the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is bounded by $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left((k+1)k^{-2}\right)^{s}$?

Comment: @GerrySmith $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is defined as an infimum over all covers. We supplied one cover that yielded this value, so the infimum can't be more than that.

Comment: Ok so it is that there are $k+1$ points which are at least $k^{-2}$ apart. So $k+1$ intervals of length $k^{-2}$ are needed to cover the set and this is the smallest such covering. Yes?

Comment: @GerrySmith Yes. Though we have a slight error that needs fixing: the $s$-measure of *each* interval of length $k^{-2}$ is $(k^{-2})^s$, so the $s$-measure of the whole cover is $(k + 1)k^{-2s}$, not $((k + 1)k^{-2})^s$. This will change our final answer slightly.

Comment: Sorry yes. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I've been looking into this a bit more and found a problem. Isn't it the case that $\{0,1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\ldots\}$ is countable and so $\dim_{\text{H}}(\{0,1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\ldots\})=0$?